# Awk: Print last N columns, where N is passed through a variable

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, awk

My input variable `$dirPath` contains directory path. The action is to be able to retrieve the last N values in the directory path, where `N` is passed through a variable `$depth`. For a fixed `N` value (say 2) I'm able to achieve this through

```
subDir=$(echo $dirPath|awk -F "/" '{n= 2; for (--n; n >= 0; n--){ printf "%s/", $(NF-n)} print ""}')
```

However if I try to replace 2 in the above command with a variable as `n=$depth`, the `subDir` variable is empty. So how can I pass a variable value to the above command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to pass a `bash` variable to `awk` then all you need is to use awk's `-v` parameter :

```
awk -v n=$depth -F "/"...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `bash`, no need for external tools such as `awk`

```
#read path constituents into array arr
IFS=/ read -ra arr <<<"$dirPath"
n=2
#print the last two
(IFS=/; printf '%s\n' "${arr[*]:(-n)}")
```